Error: MSB3073 exited with code 3 - VS2019
I am Updating all C++ projects platform toolset from Visual Studio 2012 to Visual Studio 2019.
When I am trying to perform registration of the DLL which was created during Build, it is giving below error.
In project properties -> Custom Build Step i have added the below command to perform registration,
regsvr32 /s /c "$(TargetPath)" echo regsvr32 exec. time > "$(OutDir)regsvr32.trg"
1>Performing registration
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(286,5): error MSB3073: The command "regsvr32 /s /c "D:\newomnia\Omnia\source\cpp\DependentFiles\MGNortelGPRSPreProcessor.dll"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(286,5): error MSB3073: echo regsvr32 exec. time > "..\..\..\..\DependentFiles\regsvr32.trg"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(286,5): error MSB3073: 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(286,5): error MSB3073: 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(286,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 3.

On clicking the error, it navigates to below tags within Microsoft.CppCommon.targets
    <Exec Command="%(CustomBuildStep.Command)$(_BuildSuffix)"
      StdOutEncoding = "%(CustomBuildStep.StdOutEncoding)"
      StdErrEncoding = "%(CustomBuildStep.StdErrEncoding)" />

I am able to build and register the other projects. only few projects having this issue.
The path of the DLL was in the location i specified. I even tried to directly be registering from the command prompt (As admin). still, it is failing.
Can someone please help in this.

Look in the Output window for the error message that regsvr32.exe produced.

getting this error:
"The module "MGNortelGPRSPreProcessor.dll" failed to load.
Make sure the binary is stored at the specified path or
debug it to check for problems with the binary or
dependent .DLL files.
The specified procedure could not be found."

This probably means that MGNortelGPRSPreProcessor.dll is dependent on some dll that you don't have in the same folder as MGNortelGPRSPreProcessor.dll when you executed regsvr32 . You may want to try this tool to attempt to figure out what is the needed dll: https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies

thanks @drescherjm. Some DLL was not present in the same folder.

Glad I could help. Thanks for replying.


"XXX.dll" failed to load. Make sure the binary is stored at the
specified path or debug it to check for problems with the binary or
dependent .DLL files. The specified procedure could not be found.

From How to use the Regsvr32 tool:
The 32-bit version is %systemroot%\SysWoW64\regsvr32.exe.
 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe 

The error means MGNortelGPRSPreProcessor.dll is missing  dependent libraries. Make sure that the DLLs required by MGNortelGPRSPreProcessor.dll are in the same folder or system environment path.
In addition, consider using  post-build event.

I have already added all the dependencies and all the requires DLL are in the same folder. But still the same error. @Minxin Yu

Have you tried Dependencies  tool?

yes, I have used the dependencies walker and also checked with cppdepend tool. Have added all the dependencies.

Did you choose VS2019 C++ SDK for building? There is not enough information in the current question.

Looks like you are registering 32bit all in 64 bit OS:
You have to go to:
cd C:\Windows\SysWOW64
then register using:
regsvr32 "D:\newomnia\Omnia\source\cpp\DependentFiles\MGNortelGPRSPreProcessor.dll"

I have tried your suggestion but it's not working for me. @Sanjay Shrivastava
